# Jenkins to Mule console connector

Tags: jenkins, mule

I am new to Mule Console.
Iam doing builds using Jenkins and deployments using Mule ESB console.
Currently we are trying to automate it. So is there any plugin in jenkins which helps me to connect from Jenkins to Mule ESB console. Please help me in this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this: `http://mulesoft.github.io/jenkins-connector/mule/jenkins-config.html` ?

Comment: yes, i checked it.. Bt its showing conection from Mule to Jenkins... :-( I want from jenkins to Mule

Answer (score 2):

There is a Maven plugin to connect to the Mule Management Console API: https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/Maven-Mule-REST-Plugin.

This can be configured in your maven mule project and easily triggered by Jenkins.